# Wordpress AJAX, Jquery portion sends data but PHP function doesn't run

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Here is the jquery portion to call the ajax function when someone clicks the a tag element. What I want to do is take the data value from that a tag element, pass it into the php function, and run the php function using the passed in string variable. The Jquery portion works, I can send the data value, but the PHP function doesn't even run, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$(function(){
  $('#catFilter a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).fadeOut(300);
    var x = $(this).attr('data-slug');
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

  $.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: {data: x, action: 'filter'},
    success: function(data, status) {
      console.log(x);
    },
    error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
    }
    }); // end ajax call
  });
});
```

And the PHP portion, I want to add the data value from the A tag element into the PHP array, and then run the function with the passed in parameters.

```
function filter(){
  $x = $_POST['data'];
  array_push($needleArray, $x);
  post_filter();
  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_filter', 'filter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter');
```

Comment: The ajax 'type' should be 'method' for post. Also I would strongly recommend you refrain from ever using die() command.

Comment: I used it because apparently you need it in the PHP function when doing Wordpress AJAX. Also, I changed the type to method, still doesn't seem to work. The javascript portion is indeed sending the data to the AJAX.php file, but the PHP in the functions.php is not even running it seems. I set it to echo out whatever it receives and it doesn't seem to echo out anything.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses jQuery noConflict mode in-order to avoid conflict with other javascript libraries that may uses the symbol $.
You need to change from this:

```
$(function(){
    // your code
});
```

To this:

```
jQuery(function($){
  // your code
});
```

This is the safe way to use jQuery.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#user-contributed-notes